# Getting a value from a ConfigMap in my Argo Workflow

Tags: yaml, go-templates, argo

My Argo Workflow has a template that generates the following Config Map:

```json
{
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "kind": "ConfigMap",
  "metadata": { "name": "configmap" },
  "data":
    {
      "ELASTIC_SEARCH_URL": "https://staging-aaa.domain.com",
      "EXTENSION_PATH": "/dist",
      "GRAPHQL_GATEWAY_URL": "https://graphql-gateway.stg.domain.com/graphql",
      "bucket_url": "stg-bucket/fie/to/path",
    },
}
```

I use this value in one of my other templates like this:

```yaml
...
envFrom:
- configMapRef:
    name: "{{inputs.parameters.configmap}}"
```

I also want to get a "2-in-1" by getting `bucket_url` within that output, so I created this template to test if I'm able to print what I want (I can't `withParam` over the original output, so I added `[]` around `{{steps.create-configmap.outputs.parameters.configmap}}`):

```yaml
- - name: print-with-loop
    template: print-with-loop-tmpl
    arguments:
      parameters:
        - name: data
          value: "{{item}}"
    withParam: "[{{steps.create-configmap.outputs.parameters.configmap}}]"
```

The output of this template is exactly the Config Map itself:

```
{apiVersion:v1,data:{ELASTIC_SEARCH_URL:https://staging-aaa.domain.com,EXTENSION_PATH:/dist,GRAPHQL_GATEWAY_URL:https://graphql.stg.domain.com/graphql,bucket_url:stg-bucket/fie/to/path},kind:ConfigMap,metadata:{name:env-configmap}}
```

I can also print `item.data` within that Config Map:

```
{ELASTIC_SEARCH_URL:https://staging-aaa.domain.com,EXTENSION_PATH:/dist,GRAPHQL_GATEWAY_URL:https://graphql.stg.domain.com/graphql,bucket_name:stg-bucket,ext_path:extension/stable/dist-raw.tar.gz,bucket_url:stg-bucket/extension/stable/dist-raw.tar.gz}
```

However I can't access any data within `item.data`. If I use `item.data.bucket_url` or `item.data['bucket_url']`, it doesn't work and I get errors from Argo.

I tried to manipulate the output using [sprig](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/) but I wasn't able to find a solution. Basically I'm trying to fetch `bucket_url` to use in another template within this workflow.

### Reproduce the issue yourself

1. Run your Argo server
2. Create a Workflow yaml file
3. Run `argo submit` with your new workflow file.
4. That's it :)

I made the smallest template I can that should produce the exact same result. If you run Argo locally like I do, maybe give it a try:

```yaml
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Workflow
metadata:
  generateName: test-
spec:
  entrypoint: main
  arguments:
    parameters:
      - name: cluster
        value: "stg"
      - name: version
        value: "stg/stable"

  templates:
    - name: main
      steps:
        - - name: create-configmap
            template: create-configmap-tmpl

        - - name: print-with-loop
            template: print-with-loop-tmpl
            arguments:
              parameters:
                - name: data
                  value: "{{item}}"
            withParam: "[{{steps.create-configmap.outputs.parameters.configmap}}]"

    - name: create-configmap-tmpl
      inputs:
        artifacts:
          - name: python-script
            path: /tmp/script.py
            raw:
              data: |
                import json

                def create_simple_config_map():
                    config = {
                        "ELASTIC_SEARCH_URL": "https://example-domain.com",
                        "GRAPHQL_GATEWAY_URL": "https://graphql.example.com/graphql",
                        "bucket_name": "example-bucket",
                        "ext_path": "example/path/file",
                        "bucket_url": "example-bucket/example/path/file"
                    }
                    
                    return config

                def main():
                    config = create_simple_config_map()

                    configmap = {
                        "apiVersion": "v1",
                        "kind": "ConfigMap",
                        "metadata": {
                            "name": "env-configmap"
                        },
                        "data": config
                    }

                    with open("/tmp/configmap.json", "w") as file:
                        json.dump(configmap, file, indent=4)

                    print(json.dumps([config], indent=4))

                if __name__ == "__main__":
                    main()
      container:
        image: python:3.11
        command: ["python", "/tmp/script.py"]
      outputs:
        parameters:
          - name: configmap
            valueFrom:
              path: /tmp/configmap.json

    - name: print-with-loop-tmpl
      inputs:
        parameters:
          - name: data
      script:
        image: bash
        command: [bash]
        source: |
          echo "{{inputs.parameters.data}}"
```

The step `create-configmap-tmpl` generates a valid Config Map, you can also run it locally:

```py
import json

def create_simple_config_map():
    config = {
        "ELASTIC_SEARCH_URL": "https://example-domain.com",
        "GRAPHQL_GATEWAY_URL": "https://graphql.example.com/graphql",
        "bucket_name": "example-bucket",
        "ext_path": "example/path/file",
        "bucket_url": "example-bucket/example/path/file"
    }
    
    return config

def main():
    config = create_simple_config_map()

    configmap = {
        "apiVersion": "v1",
        "kind": "ConfigMap",
        "metadata": {
            "name": "configmap"
        },
        "data": config
    }

    with open("/tmp/configmap.json", "w") as file:
        json.dump(configmap, file, indent=4)

    print(json.dumps([config], indent=4))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The output of this script is the following:

```json
{
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "kind": "ConfigMap",
    "metadata": {
        "name": "configmap"
    },
    "data": {
        "ELASTIC_SEARCH_URL": "https://example-domain.com",
        "GRAPHQL_GATEWAY_URL": "https://graphql.example.com/graphql",
        "bucket_name": "example-bucket",
        "ext_path": "example/path/file",
        "bucket_url": "example-bucket/example/path/file"
    }
}
```

You can now try to play around with the printing:

```yaml
- - name: print-with-loop
    template: print-with-loop-tmpl
    arguments:
    parameters:
        - name: data
        value: "{{item}}"
    withParam: "[{{steps.create-configmap.outputs.parameters.configmap}}]"
```

- If we use `item`, it prints the entire Config Map
- If we use `item.data`, it would also work.

The problem is accessing `item.data.bucket_url` or `item.data['bucket_url']`. It won't work.
As mentioned, I tried various `sprig` functions like `toJson`, lists and dict manipulation, but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a different parameter for `withParam`:

```yaml
        - - name: print-with-loop
            template: print-with-loop-tmpl
            arguments:
              parameters:
                - name: data
                  value: "{{item.bucket_url}}"
            withParam: "{{steps.create-configmap.outputs.result}}"
```

Since I'm printing the `json.dump` that I'm doing in the script that generates the ConfigMap, I can easily access `bucket_url`. The above template's output is exactly what I needed.